# Trying to use setfacl to allow script owner to delete cache file

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, setfacl

I want to use setfacl to allow a php script owner to delete fastcgi_cache_path files that are owned by nginx. The user has been added to the nginx group.

I have tried: `setfacl -d -m u:user:rwx cache`, but it's not working. The script is not even seeing the file using `file_exists()` though I've verified it does exist at that location.

What do I need to do? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

A thought of permissions, are you sure that the designated user has at least 'x' access to the all elements in the entire directory path?

For example, suppose you have a path such as /a/cache. If the user has NO access to directory /a then the user will be unable to see, much less access, the file cache regardless of its permission.

Comment: I added the 'setfacl' starting with the 'cache' directory. The full path is: /var/lib/nginx/cache/ ... all the cache files get created in subfolders of that.

Comment: So I'd have to set it all the way back to /var? Would that then give the user permissions to everything in that path?